# How do I get a specific value using HttpParams in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to get a specific object from a JSON file through an HTTP request that passes a String as a parameter. But the result I get are all objects present in the JSON file.

For example:
I have the following example.JSON:

```
[
 {"id": "AAA", "name": "foo"},
 {"id": "AAAB", "name": "bar"},
]
```

In the ExampleService I've the following code:

```
getExampleById (id: string): Observable<Example> {
     return this.http.get<Example>('../assets/example.json', { params: new HttpParams().set('id', id)});}
```

The URL is localhost:4200/assets/example.json?id=AAA

I would like that when passing the parameter id = "AAA", return only {"id": "AAA", "name": "foo"} but the HTTP response returns all JSON objects.

In the ExampleComponent I've:

```
getExampleById(id: string): void {
this.exService.getExampleById(id).subscribe((data: Example) => this.example = {

  id: data['id'],
  name: data['name'],

} );
```

The page.html doesn't updates de object Example. I don't know what and where is the problem. I suspect the problem is in the http response.

Comment: Unless your back end (ie. your end point) filters the results based on the query string this wont work. I suspect you are just getting a `json` file from disk, passing query parameters to that url won't do anything. The server has to have some implementation and act on these if you want filtering.

Comment: @Igor Makes perfect sense. Thank you.